# Excel macro - how to break wrapped text into rows for merged columns?

Tags: vba, excel, merge, split

I have to import data from PDF to SAS, and one step involves converting the PDF data to excel spreadsheet before converting to text for simpler SAS import. Usually the PDF data converts fine into excel, with few errors. As I am trying to import older data, it is getting quite messy and some of the rows get wrapped in a single cell. I am trying to figure out if there is a macro possible which can help me fix this error in sheets without too much manual manipulation. I have never programmed in VBA before so I am quite new to excel macros.

Here is the example of messy data:

[image]

Here is the example of normal data:

[image]

(*Note the data values in the two images are different, just for example formatting)

I have tried working on a macro. For this, I copy the messy data into another sheet, and run the macro which outputs corrected data on a separate sheet, and then i copy the corrected data over the messy one in the original spreadsheet.
After trying to code the macro, I was unable to figure out how to tell excel to take the data in columns C,D,E,F which are all merged into one cell and break that wrapped text, and so on for other merged columns (as shown in messy data image). 
Here is my current code that I got after watching some tutorials:

```
Sub Split_Text_to_Rows()
Dim splitVals1 As Variant
Dim splitVals2 As Variant

Dim totalVals As Long

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)

sh2.Cells.Clear
lrow1 = sh1.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To lrow1

splitVals1 = Split(sh1.Cells(j, 1), Chr(10))
splitVals2 = Split(sh1.Cells(j, 2), Chr(10))

    For i = LBound(splitVals1) To UBound(splitVals1)
        lrow2 = sh2.Range("A65356").End(xlUp).Row
        sh2.Cells(lrow2 + 1, 1) = splitVals1(i)
    Next i

    For k = LBound(splitVals2) To UBound(splitVals2)
        lrow3 = sh2.Range("B65356").End(xlUp).Row
         sh2.Cells(lrow3 + 1, 2) = splitVals2(k)
    Next k

Next j

End Sub
```

As you can see, my code is also quite messy. Although, I got the code to work for columns A and B, when I get to column C - "Motor Vehicle Theft" and so on, I am not sure how to separate that wrapped text since they are merged in columns C,D,E,F. I would also like to keep the columns I to Q as two merged rows even after macro splits 1 row into 2 (shown in normal data image) and then continue splitting cells till column Z.
Any tips would be helpful! Please let me know if more information or clarification is needed.

Comment: Aren't merged cells fun?  I try to avoid them whenever possible.  With regard to the merging of `C4:E4`, all of the data will be in `C4` (the upper left cell of the merged area), so that's all you need to look at and figure out how you want to split it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld -- Oh! I used the upper left cell for merged area for split and copied the code over while changing variable names and that worked! Thanks. Now, I am trying to figure out how to output the 4 columns that need to be merged to I can simply copy and replace the entire "messy" sub-selection of data. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is not at all clear to me how you want to handle the results.  It is trivial to split the data in C4 by the LineFeed character, as you are doing.  I would suggest to avoid merged cells.  So I would make each a separate row; you'll have a bunch of blank columns, but you can deal with that by formatting.  And you may have to repeat entries in different rows, depending on how you want things to come out at the end; again, you should be able to make things appear as you wish by centering across cells (without merging) and by blanking out some entries (font the same color as background).

Answer (score 0):

I often find that the best approach is to first paste the data into Word, do some clean-up there, format it as a Word table, and then transfer it into Excel.  The reason is that Word has very powerful find/replace features which allow you to quickly convert a mess into something sensible. Since you didn't provide example data I could paste in, I randomly found a pdf on the web to show one approach. The key in this case was noticing that each column begins with a space followed by a digit. So I did a search for " ^#" (a space followed by 'any digit') and replaced it by "^t" (tab character). Next, I used Word's 'Convert to Table' feature, and after that the data table is ready for pasting into Excel.

[image]